# Extract last occurrence before 'unknown' in bash

Tags: awk

There's a tsv table:

```
item_1    bla    0.5    124  1;0    word1    wordk    word7    unknown
item_3    bla_1  0.11   2    0;99   word2    wordm    unknown
item_x    blabl  333    11   1;0;0  word     worda    word6    word7    word16    unknown
item_y    bla_3  0.51   6    0;99   words    unknown  unknown unknown
```

I want to retrieve a list of items corresponding to the **last known word** before **unknown**, meaning:

```
    item_1    word7
    item_3    wordm
    ...
    item_x    word16
    item_y    words
```

I was trying something like `cut -f` but don't understand how exactly specify this condition *before unknown*.

Any ideas?

@Upd
To specify the question, this is the real data:

```
item_1        classified        based on 1/2  1;1413        word 1        wordl        not classified        not classified        not classified        not classified        not classified
item_10       classified        based on 1/1  1;98        word 2        not classified        not classified        not classified        not classified                not classified        not classified
item_17       classified        based on 1/1  1;13156       word1        word m        not classified        not classified        not classified        not classified        not classified
item_13       classified        based on 1/1  1;131        word3        wordp        word s        word z        not classified        not classified        not classified
```

As you can see, multiple `not classified` can occur in a row; after `not classified` there's never a known word, some rows can contain no `not classified`. There are always 7 fields of words and/or `not classified` after the `1;98` pattern. The 2nd field can either be `unclassified` or `classified`. Some known words may contain spaces.

Comment: Is `unkown` always the last word on the line or could it appear elsewhere in the order? If the latter then include that case in your sample input/output. And get rid of the `...`s - they add no value and make your sample untestable without editing.

Comment: Also: can `unknown` appear more than once on a line, and if so, how can that be handled? Can there be lines where `unknown` doesn't appear **at all** - and so, how should those lines be handled? Does `unknown` always appear as a complete "field" (separated by tabs), or can it be part of a field - and if it can, how should that be handled? If none of these special situations can occur, you should say so explicitly in the problem statement. If you don't know, you need to ask your business user (unless it's yourself).

Comment: Updated accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

***1st solution:*** Could you please try following(tested and written with shown samples).

```
awk '{for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){if($i=="unknown"){print $1,$(i-1)}}}' Input_file
```

***Explanation:*** Adding detailed explanation for above code.

```
awk '                     ##Starting awk program from here.
{
  for(i=2;i<=NF;i++){     ##Starting for loop from here from 2nd field to last field of current line.
    if($i=="unknown"){    ##Checking condition if current field is unknown then do following.
      print $1,$(i-1)     ##Printing 1st and previous field here.
    }
  }
}
' Input_file              ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

---

---

***2nd solution:*** Adding 1 more solution without loop here.

```
awk '
match($0,/ [^ ]* +unknown/){
  value=substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH)
  gsub(/^ +| +unknown/,"",value)
  print $1,value
}
'  Input_file
```

Comment: Notice the **tsv** in the original post. The fields are delimited by tabs, not by spaces. This won't affect the first solution, but it will affect the second.

Comment: @mathguy, yeah, that's the reason I mentioned that written code with shown samples only, if OP changes samples will edit my code accordingly then,cheers.

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 I tried these solutions, they didn't work on my data. My bad, so I updated the question.

Answer (score 2):

From each line, remove the "unknown" suffix, then you can print the first and last fields.

```sh
awk -v OFS="\t" '{sub(/[[:space:]]+unknown.*/, ""); print $1, $NF}' file
```

or the equivalent but "cleverer"

```sh
perl -slne 's/\bunknown.*//; print +(split)[0,-1]' -- -,=$'\t' file
```

Comment: smart trimming!

Answer (score 1):

with `sed`

```
$ sed -E 's/(^\S+).*\s(\S+)\s+unknown.*/\1 \2/' file

item_1 word7
item_3 wordm
...
item_x word16
item_y words
```

Comment: Your solution assumes the fields are separated by spaces. The OP said the file is `tsv`, that is - tab-separated values. I doubt that he would have said "tsv" unless he actually meant it.

Comment: @mathguy, `\s` is a "whitespace" character: that includes tabs.

Comment: Right - but the OP's tokens may contain spaces, which presumably should be preserved, not trimmed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, you want to print two fields: the first one and the last but one, and the number of fields is not the same for each row. Moreover, you don't know the value of the last field.

Try:

```
awk '{print $1, $(NF - 1)}' Input_file
```